# Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller

Tags: flash, runtime-error, removechild

I just started making a really simple video game for a class and I have a random score point spawner. This function works fine, nothing goes wrong, but when I publish the game and play it with Flashy Player, it shows up with the error message

> Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

I've just been dismissing it since the program works other than the alert prompt, but I need to remove that.

```
function spawnscore()
{
    i = 0
    while (i == 0)
    {
        var pointy = Math.random()*640
        var pointx = Math.random()*747

        var pointcirc:warning = new warning();
        addChild(pointcirc);
        pointappearmusic.play();
        setTimeout(removepoint, 1500);
        pointcirc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, scoreclicked);

        function scoreclicked()
        {
            pointsound10.play();
            removeChild(pointcirc);
            score += 10;
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, scoreclicked);
        }

        function removepoint()
        {
            // I'm pretty sure this is the problem
            removeChild(pointcirc);
        }

        pointcirc.x = pointx;
        pointcirc.y = pointy;
        break;
    }

    return;
}
```

I'm pretty sure my problem is in the removepoint function, but I can't figure out what to do.

Edit : highlight error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means you're trying to remove a `DisplayObject` from a container when it's not actually a child of that container, so it looks like what's happening is `scoreclicked()` runs and removes `pointcirc`, then `removepoint` tries to remove it again.

You just need to check if `pointcirc` has already been removed in  `removepoint()`. There are lots different ways to do that: You could set a `pointRemoved` variable, or just set `pointcirc = null` after it's removed and check that. You can also check directly using [`DisplayObjectContainer.contains()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#contains%28%29), or just see if [`pointcirc.parent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#parent) exists.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is harmless, you can ignore it with try/catch:

```
try
{
    removeChild(pointcirc);
}
catch(e:Error){}
```

I should warn you that if this `while` were to actually loop instead of just `break`ing at the end, you probably won't get the behavior you're expecting.

The `pointcirc` in `removepoint` only refers to the last value of `pointcirc` when `spawnscore` returned.  That would be the value after the last loop, meaning every time `removepoint` is called, it's trying to remove the last `pointcirc`.

You can avoid this problem by putting the code in the loop into a closure:

```
function spawnscore()
{
    i = 0
    while (i == 0)
    {
        var pointy = Math.random()*640
        var pointx = Math.random()*747

        (function(pointcirc:warning)
        {
            var pointcirc:warning = new warning();
            addChild(pointcirc);
            pointappearmusic.play();

            var timeoutId:int = setTimeout(removepoint, 1500);

            pointcirc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, scoreclicked);

            function scoreclicked()
            {
                pointsound10.play();
                removeChild(pointcirc);
                score += 10;
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, scoreclicked);
            }

            function removepoint()
            {
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                removeChild(pointcirc);
            }
        })(pointcirc);

        pointcirc.x = pointx;
        pointcirc.y = pointy;
        break;
    }

    return;
}
```

See http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/